# Any way to accordingly color separate parts of these LaTeX meshes with python?

Tags: python, add-on, import, color, color-management

I'm writing some functions in python which implement the latex2blender addon. Information about this addon can be found here: https://github.com/ghseeli/latex2blender

I'm able to create a few strings with a color associated to each string. I then combine these strings into one line, send the string to the latex compiler, and spawn in a line of latex with separate parts of the latex mesh colored accordingly.

For example, I have created a "Str" class so I can associate hex colors with strings.

```
str0 = Str("$\dfrac{1}{2}$", 0xE7E7E7)
str1 = Str(" is a ratio", 0xBE0000)
```

I then store str0 and str1 into a list and send the list into a "write" function

```
strs = [str0, str1]
write(strs)
```

I'm able to display the LaTeX fine and I split the spawned in LaTeX mesh by loose parts. However, coloring the individual meshes gets tricky. I don't think there's a way to be able to tell python which mesh came from which string because the information is lost when compiled. I just set all of the meshes to 0xBE0000.

[image]

The following image would be my desired output:
[image]

I've thought about splitting things up into multiple compiles and then aligning the meshes afterwards. For example, I could compile "$\dfrac{1}{2}$" set its color to 0xE7E7E7, and then separately compile "is a ratio", and then color is 0xBE0000. However, these latex figures don't spawn in at consistent heights. Aligning them is a pain and I've actually tried to do this. I've played with bounding boxes, resetting the objects origin, etc, but there's just no clean way to do so.

If there was some way to be able to count how many mesh object come from each Str object, that would be nice. The code "\dfrac{1}{2}" produces three disjoint mesh objects The 1, the overline, and the 2. Whereas the string itself has 12 elements, so there's no correlation there.

[image]